# Include Max mega menu Plugin into theme

Tags: plugins, theme-development, menus, themes

I want to add the [Max Mega Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/megamenu/) plugin into my theme for a project.

What i've done:

- copy and paste plugin folder into my theme
- include `megamenu.php` file into my theme `function.php` file

Needed to work:

- include with theme
- active when theme active

So, how can I include this plugin and activate it when my theme is activated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include a plugin directly inside a theme then it will be rejected by both the WordPress.org theme directory and ThemeForest.

You should use TGMPA for including plugins with themes: http://tgmpluginactivation.com/

Further reading: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-tgm-plugin-activation-library-in-your-themes--cms-20901

Using TGMPA means the plugin remains a plugin, WordPress loads it in the normal 'plugin' way, and users will get plugin updates as they're released.

Comment: thanks for sharing those links it's very helpful. Another thing is this is a custom project for my client.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply include a plugin in your theme by calling it from your `functions.php`. The reason is that if the user already has the same plugin installed, this will lead to a fatal error.

Also, you shouldn't move parts of the plugin to your theme, because you don't know how the plugin works internally. It might be looking for a file that isn't there and throw an error.

So, the right way to do this is have the complete plugin in a subdirectory of your theme and call it only after you have checked whether it hasn't already be loaded. This can be done by checking the existence of a certain function or class that you know is available in the plugin. Sample code:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'wpse237683_load_plugin');

function wpse237683_load_plugin() {
    if (!class_exists('wpse237683')) {
        include_once (get_template_directory() . 'plugins/wpse237683/wpse237683.php');
        }
    }
```

There are still various pitfalls. You can try solving these yourself or use a [PHP library like TGMPA](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/) that will manage this for you.

Comment: Prefer `get_template_directory()` to `TEMPLATEPATH`.

Comment: @bravokeyl True. Fixed.

Comment: thanks for your tips. I think TGMPA is the best solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

In addition with Tom Hemsley's answer, this is a list of services and open sources that might be useful:

- [WP Package Editor](https://wordpress.recuweb.com/)

> WP2E is a service allowing developers to create and manage installation
> packages to deliver and maintain sets of interdependent themes and
> plugins.

- [TGM Plugin Activation](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/)

> TGM Plugin Activation is a PHP library that allows you to easily
> require or recommend plugins for your WordPress themes (and plugins).

- [WPFavs](https://wpfavs.com/)

> It is a Free WordPress plugin manager and bulk installation tool

- [WP Plugin Dependencies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-dependencies/)

> This meta-plugin allows regular plugins to specify other plugins that
> they depend upon.

- [WP Dependency Installer](https://github.com/afragen/wp-dependency-installer)

> A lightweight class to add to WordPress plugins/themes to
> automatically install plugin dependencies.